# get value of specific resource string

Tags: c#, multilingual, resourcemanager

I have developed a multilingual application where my resource file resides in App_GlobalResources. Resource file structure is as below:

App_GlobalResources

--------Resource.ar.resx

--------Resource.resx

I want to display resourcekey value with both culture. How can I get value of specific resourcekey in both culture.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with ResourceManager

```
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(*Your Resource Class*));
        rm.GetString("Resource Key", new CultureInfo("en"));
        rm.GetString("Resource Key", new CultureInfo("ar"));
```

Comment: Steve, It still give me value with culture en only.

Comment: @Ronak that means the same key doesn't exist in your Resource.ar.resx file